# How to create popup using datatables when image is clicked?

Tags: datatables

---

"As am new to datatables concept I got confused to create popup when image is clicked" I dont know any dataTables concept that involves popups on images?

Comment: "_As am new to datatables concept I got confused to create popup when image is clicked_" I dont know any dataTables concept that involves popups on images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with datatables.
But it's quite easy to do with javascript.
Here is a very simple example and you can use it as basic;

**CSS**

```
<style>
    button{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
    }
    #PopUp{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="funcPop()" id="btnPop"><img src=""></button>
<div id="PopUp">
    <h1>POPUP</h1>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    funcPop = function(){
        document.getElementById('btnPop').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('PopUp').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Pay attention that this code WON'T work for classes, which means if you add to button a class and not id - you'll need another solution, smthng like (of course change id's to classes):

```
$('.btnPop').click(function(){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("PopUp");
     for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'table-row';
     }
});
```

And don't forget that you have a lot of nice, light and easy-to-use jQuery plugins

Comment: Is there any jquery plugin available to popup each row ?

Comment: Check [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/) one. You'll find "Photo lightbox" for popping up images.
As i'm not sure what exactly you need I can't suggest exact plugin or example. But I'm sure you'll find nice things there :)

Comment: And of couse [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) of jQueary. The most basic popup with basic effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and some jquery code:
**Script**

```
$('#myDataTable > tr > td > img.className').on('click',function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
    ...
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```